How to animate a destroyed object?
I have a wall and a ball flies into the wall, as well as the Cell Fracture addon BUT upon collision the ball should fly apart (not the wall), but I can’t animate 100-odd pieces of the ball so that they fly into the wall and break. Rigidbody won't let me animate it


hello do you mean that the ball hit the wall and breaks?

@moonboots, Yes!

Create your wall, give it Rigid Body > Type > Passive, create your ball, give it Rigid Body > Type > Active, create your animation of a ball hitting a wall, let say it is supposd to hit at frame 11, at frame 10 keyframe the Animated option on:

At frame 11 keyframe it off:

Back to frame 1, fracture cell your ball, once done, put the 3D cursor at the center of the sphere with ShiftS > Cursor to Selected, select all the pieces and right click > Set Origin > Origin to 3D Cursor:

Now in the Outliner, select all the pieces and Ctrl select the original ball:

Copy the animation of the original ball with CtrlL > Link Aniation Data:

Also copy the rigid body settings with Object > Rigid Body > Copy from Active:

Here is the animation:

Now you just need to keyframe the sphere and pieces visibility so that the sphere is visible from frame 1 to 10 and invisible afterwards, and vice-versa for the pieces. Select the sphere, create a brand new action from the existing one:

Keyframe its visibility in the Outliner, at frame 10 make it visible and keyframe, at frame 11 make it invisible and keyframe:

Do the opposite for the pieces...

I do not know why, but after this destroyed ball looks like: https://ibb.co/60J8rgW

Oh yes I get it, when you've done the cell fracture, put the 3D cursor at the center of the sphere, select all the pieces and right click > Set Origin > Origin to 3D Cursor
